# How do i send automatic emails using custom namecheap domain?

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib, namecheap

hello i just bought custom email address from namecheap. i am trying to figure out how to send emails automatically. this is my code:

```
import smtplib #socket
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
sender_email="user@custom.xyz"
password = "password"
smtp_host="mail.privateemail.com"
#socket.gaierror,smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
def send_mail(send_to,subject,content):
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host,587) as smtp:
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login(user=sender_email,password=password) #socket.gaierror,smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        message = MIMEText(f'{content}')
        message['subject'] = subject
        message['to'] = send_to
        
        try:
            
            smtp.sendmail(sender_email,send_to, msg=message.as_string())
        except Exception or ExceptionGroup as e:
            print(f"E: {e}") 
send_mail(send_to="test@example.com",subject="subject",content="description here.")
```

but it doesn't send anything nor prints any error in console. it works fine with outlook.

what should have happened: it should send email to specified email.
what actually happened: it doesn't send email nor prints anything on console.

Comment: `sendmail` has a return value. What do you see if you print it?